# Is my Hasse diagram for the poset relation correct?

Tags: relations

${ (a,e), (b,f), (d,b), (d,g), (e,c), (c,b), (g,f), (e,g) }$ - The relation

My confusion lies with $(c,b)$ would $c$ be above $b$ in the diagram?

*Please ignore the highlighting

The image below is of my drawing of the relation as a Hasse diagram.

[image: The image below is my depiction]

Comment: $c$ should be below $b$, and $e$ should be below $g$.

Comment: Thought so, thanks peterwhy.